# Jersey UK pension

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

I have a Jersey OAP Pension which was due for commencement in November 2013.

The States of Jersey were informed of my UK address in the past but the Service say only 6 months back pay is payable when maturity date was in 2013! Is their reply fair and correct?

- My age in 2013 was 60.
- The pension did not commence in 2013 although I had contacted them and sent my Uk address. I assumed that they would contact recipients due to constant changes in law.
- They made no contact. (I had a cerebral haemorrhage in 2010 and my husband passed away in 2011. Major Surgery in 2011 also.)
- The Service will only pay back 6 months prior to first speaking to them recently.

If it is a Pension Fund what would happen to the remainder 2.5 years.?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the underlying legislation to back this up, but the [Jersey government's website](https://www.gov.je/Benefits/PensionsRetirement/Pages/HowPensionWorks.aspx#anchor-4) says:

> If you're living in Jersey and you've paid contributions in the last six years, you should receive a letter from us about three months before you reach your 65th birthday.

([The pension age is actually 60](https://www.gov.je/Benefits/PensionsRetirement/Pages/HowPensionWorks.aspx#anchor-3) for women who were registered with Social Security before 1975)

The page then goes on to talk about a form you can fill in if you don't get a letter, for example because you live outside Jersey, and explicitly says:

> We can't back-date a pension for more than six months before the date you claim.

So I doubt you have any way to get back the lost 2.5 years. They won't consider they had any obligation to write to you. You could try using the [Jersey government's complaints system](https://www.gov.je/Government/Comments/Pages/StatesJerseyComplaintsBoard.aspx), maybe using your ill-health as an extenuating circumstance for why you couldn't claim earlier, but it seems unlikely you'd get anywhere.

As to where the money that you missed out on would go, Government pension funds don't have a specific pot of money allocated to an individual. Indeed, they can't know how much your pension will cost as it depends on how long you live. Pensions are paid out of the general funds of the scheme and any money not paid out just means the scheme as a whole is in slightly better shape financially and ultimately more likely to remain afloat or require less government support. Many government pension schemes don't have a specific fund at all - pensions are just paid out of the government's current revenue.